# Sind zusammenbrechen und kaputtgehen austauschbar?

Tags: difference, verb

> Mein Wagen ist **kaputtgegangen** und ich muss ihn reparieren lassen.
>
> Mein Wagen ist **zusammengebrochen** und ich muss ihn reparieren lassen.

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen den beiden? Kann man sie gegeneinander austauschen?

Comment: *zusammengebracht* is something completely different than *zusammenbrechen*! --> i assume you mean ***zusammengebrochen***?

Comment: Sie haben einen kleinen Überlappungsbereich, aber ansonsten wenig miteinander zu tun. _Zusammenbrechen_ und das englische _break down_ sind falsche Freunde. Mehr Details im Wörterbuch.

Comment: @DJCrashdummy: Ich habe die Frage schon bearbeitet. (Die Form _gebracht_ gehört zu _bringen_.)

Comment: Could you add any information, as to why you think they may be generally interchangeable?

Comment: Ein Auto und sonstige Maschinen können ***auseinanderfallen***, wenn sie sich z.B. wegen Rost in einzelne Teile auflösen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nach meinem Sprachverständnis involviert zusammenbrechen in irgendeiner Form dass große Teile des Ganzen herunterfallen.

Also:

> Das Dach ist kaputtgegangen.

Würde bedeuten es gibt ein Loch oder einen anderen Schaden am Dach, es kann aber insgesamt noch halbwegs instand sein.

> Das Dach ist zusammengebrochen.

Große Teile des Daches sind tatsächlich in den darunterliegenden Teil des Hauses gestürzt.

Die beiden Wörter sind in der Benutzung nicht austauschbar.

Answer (score 11):

Diese Begriffe sind nicht allgemein austauschbar. „Zusammenbrechen“ deutet auf einen Kollaps hin, der ja auch Zusammenbruch genannt wird. Daher passt im Folgenden nur zusammenbrechen:

> Der Mann brach unter Schmerzen zusammen.

Und auch hier erscheint es mir besser:

> Trotz der Last des Schnees hielten die Säulen stand und brachen nicht zusammen.

Merke insbesondere: Auch ein Mensch kann zusammenbrechen, nicht aber „kaputtgehen“.

Nach meinem Gefühl passt „kaputtgehen“ am besten bei mechanischen Schäden:

> Die Uhr ging kaputt.

Der Duden nennt aber auch die Beispiele:

> der Pullover geht kaputt (bekommt Löcher)
>
> viele Pflanzen sind durch den Frost kaputtgegangen (eingegangen)

Aufgrund des Gesagten würde ich im konkreten Falle des Wagens bei „kaputtgehen“ an irgendeinen Schaden denken, bei „zusammenbrechen“ aber an einen regelrechten Kollaps: Achsenbruch, Deichselbruch oder Ähnliches.

Answer (score 3):

"kaputtgehen" impliziert für mich eigentlich nur, dass etwas nicht mehr funktioniert. Weshalb es nicht mehr funktioniert ist zweitrangig:

> Die Uhr ist kaputtgegangen.

, kann bedeuten dass irgendetwas in der Mechanik fehlerhaft ist und deshalb nicht mehr die korrekte Zeit angezeigt wird. Es könnte aber auch bedeuten, dass ein Laster darübergefahren ist und die Uhr komplett zerstört ist. Sie ist immer noch "kaputt", soll heissen "funktioniert" nicht mehr.

"zusammenbrechen" ist spezifischer. Es beschreibt, dass etwas seine strukturelle Integrität verliert, etwa ein Gerüst, ein altes Haus, etc. Ein Auto kann nur zusammenbrechen, wenn es richtig alt und rostig ist - wie von Ludi schon beschrieben ist das Problem wohl, dass "break down" ein false friend zu zusammenbrechen ist.

> Der Stuhl ist kaputtgegangen.

würde normalerweise als kleinerer Schaden interpretiert werden - z.B. wenn die Sitzfläche oder eine Nut locker ist. (Es *kann* auch ein grösserer Schaden sein, aber das wäre nicht mein erster Gedanke)

> Der Stuhl ist zusammengebrochen.

impliziert, dass falls jemand auf dem Stuhl saß, dieser jetzt vermutlich auf dem Boden sitzt :)

PS: Wenn du schreibst "Mein Wagen ist zusammengebrochen" denke ich in erster Linie and einen alten Holzkarren mit Speichenrädern aus Holz, nicht an ein Auto - denn nur diese können wirklich zusammenbrechen.

Comment: Allerdings sagt man auch "Die Netzwerkverbindung ist zusammengebrochen".